# How to remove an entire row in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid

I'm using the grid technique in Tkinter, Python. The code below runs when the user presses a button. But I can't get it to remove the widgets it created (all of which are on row 5) when the user clicks the button again.
Here is the procedure:

```
def create_equation(self):
    R = int(self.entReactants.get())
    for i in range(R):
        entRCompound = Entry(self.kcFrame, width=10)
        entRCompound.grid(row=5,column=i*2)
        entRCompound.config(bg="SpringGreen")
        if i == R-1:
            lblReverse = GenLabel(self.kcFrame,text=" ⇌ ")
            lblReverse.grid(row=5, column=i*2+1)
            lblReverse.config(bg="aqua")
        else:
            lblPlus = GenLabel(self.kcFrame,text=" + ")
            lblPlus.grid(row=5, column=i*2+1)
            lblPlus.config(bg="aqua")
    for i in range(int(self.entProducts.get())):
        entPCompound = Entry(self.kcFrame, width=10)
        entPCompound.grid(row=5,column=R*2+i*2)
        entPCompound.config(bg="orange")
        if i != int(self.entProducts.get())-1:
            lblPlus = GenLabel(self.kcFrame,text=" + ")
            lblPlus.grid(row=5, column=R*2+i*2+1)
            lblPlus.config(bg="aqua")
```

When the button is pressed, I want it to delete the widgets it created when the button was last pressed and create the new set of widgets. This code is executed for the first press of the button as well, so there would not be anything on row 5 before it is pressed.

Any ideas?